# What types of antennas are used in a Piper Seneca PA34-200?

Tags: radio, piper-pa-34

What types of antenna are used in the Piper Seneca PA34-200 and where are they are located? The manual is not giving the specific answer to the question. Also, what is the frequency range of the antennas?

Comment: You may not be looking in the correct manual.  For Cessna for comparison, there is the POH, the parts manual, a seperate engine manual, and a seperate electronics manual.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We have a [generic question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44305/62) on light aircraft antennas already that might be helpful, although it doesn't give specific details of the PA34. And [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51349/62) has some information about frequencies, but the details (e.g. frequency spacing) may be different in different parts of the world.

Comment: Unless you get the plane right from the factory, the manual won’t help much. This post answers the question. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44305/how-many-antennae-are-there-on-a-typical-small-aircraft-and-how-are-they-connec/44330#44330

Comment: Are you trying to get a full list of every antenna on the plane and its frequency? What use would such a list be?

Answer (score 1):

There can be quite a few antennas:

- VHF Comm
- VOR
- Localizer
- Glide slope
- DME
- ADF
- Transponder
- Marker beacon
- GPS
- ELT with integral GPS receiver
- ELT
- FM Receiver

You can search for antenna at a site like [chiefaircraft.com](http://www.chiefaircraft.com) to see what they look like and the frequencies they are designed for. Or go to a manufacturer website, like COMANT Industries, for the same.

Some may have multiple functions in one antenna.

Typical locations:

- Top of fuselage/wing, (VHF comm, GPS)
- bottom of fuselage (belly), (transponder, marker beacon, VHF comm)
- top of tail, (VOR, glide slope)

Comment: If it is an older aircraft, you might have a Loran antenna as well. This post https://www.touringmachine.com/Articles/communication/2720/ has some common ones.